# Coupa apis for update operation with ids greater than 10 digit

Tags: rest

I'm working on update operation and trying to update with invalid id which is greater than 10 digit.
Ex. `PUT /api/addresses/76412345678`

For the above api I receive 400 status code with no error message from the api. It is difficult to know what it the error with just 400 status code.

Please confirm on how to handle this error? Will the api community be handling this error from their end?

Comment: Is it your own service or are just querying an API? Maybe the API only accepts IDs that fit into an `int`.

Comment: Im using coupa apis in my service.